# PHP Email Form with Redirect

Tags: php, email

First let me start of that I do not know that much about php and html.  I would like to create a php form with a redirect to the home page. Anytime I fill out the contact form it does not send out an email nor does it do anything on the page. 

Here is the html:

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="post" class="contact-form" id="contact-form">
<fieldset class="form-rows row">
    <div class="form-row column medium-6">
        <label for="contact-name">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="contact-name" placeholder="e.g. John Smith"> </div>
    <div class="form-row column medium-6">
        <label for="contact-email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="contact-email" placeholder="e.g. john.smith@abc.com"> </div>
    <div class="form-row column medium-12 half">
        <label for="contact-phone">Phone number
            <br><small>We promise we will only use your phone number to contact you regarding this message.</small></label>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="contact-phone" class="half" placeholder="e.g. 123 456 7890">
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="for-rows row">
    <div class="form-row column medium-12">
        <label for="contact-subject">Message subject</label>
        <select name="subject" id="contact-subject">
            <option value="">Please select one</option>
            <option value="1">General enquiry</option>
            <option value="2">I'd like to say thank you!</option>
            <option value="2">Something wasn't right with my order!</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-rows row">
    <div class="form-row column">
        <label for="contact-message">Your message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="contact-message" rows="8" placeholder="Enter message here &hellip;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row column">
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="contact-newsletter" placeholder="">
        <label for="contact-newsletter">I would like to receive information about news, promotions, customer surveys, competitions, exclusive offers, events.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row form-button column">
        <button type="submit" class="button-orange">Send Message</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h3>Your information</h3>
            <p>We will use your information for dealing with your request and, if you agree, to contact you with information about news, promotions, customer surveys, competitions, exclusive offers, events and other information we think may be of interest to you. We will not share your information for marketing purposes with any third party.</p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$field_subject = $_POST['subject'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'email@example.com';
 $subject = $field_subject;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'index.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your redirection is senseless, you should use php header like this:

```
if ($mail_status) { 
    header('Location: index.html');
}
else {
    header('Location: contact.html');
}
```

the mail function looks ok, I would recomend you use [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) because the mails need proper headers to be properly accepted.

You could do var_dump($_POST); die(); to see if you're recieving the _POST properly.

also mail() = true [doesnt mean it reached its destination](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Your problem could be server more than php

Are you doing this in local server? This wont work, use [test mail server](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) for debugging purposes.

Are you doing this in a host? Check php.ini permissions, try with a simple script `mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);` check the response and if it actually delivers.

Comment: we have not been using a test mail server and we have been uploading the website to Godaddy to see if it works. Where do i find  the php.ini permissions? We are very new to this.

Comment: testmail server its only for local. As you're not on local try doing a simple .php script, call it 'testmail.php', and do var_dump(mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg)); is it false? you have no permissions, is it true? you should recieve the email, if you dont then use phpmailer

Comment: I uploaded the website again and clicked submit and here is what i got: site.js:2254 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'captcha' of undefined(anonymous function) @ site.js:2254c @ libs.js:1534add @ libs.js:1549(anonymous function) @ site.js:2253dispatch @ libs.js:1901g.handle @ libs.js:1853

Comment: Something is really wrong with all the things you guys copy and pasted, because on the form you show there is not captcha.

Comment: i checked the java script and i found this: ' ail(function(t) {
                    if (t.responseJSON.captcha) e(o, !1, "Please tick below to confirm you're not a robot!");
                    else {
                        var i = t.responseJSON ? t.responseJSON.details.errors : "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again.";
                        e(o, i) '

Comment: I insist, the problem is not the php nor the redirection, so the question is wrong, or not wrong but not related to your real problem. You have ajax and php with redirection? that is wrong.

Comment: So what do I do to fix the problem as fast as I can?

Comment: Startover or hire a programmer

Comment: I deleted the java script and I got this on my screen after I changed the php: http://prntscr.com/creqvv